# Jedis "Unexpected End of Stream" exception?

Tags: apache-storm, jedis

I am using Jedis in my Apache Storm application and am often seeing the below Exception.

I suspect this is due to the parallelism in Storm, but I don't see why it would cause this Exception.

I have multiple instances of a "Bolt" which retrieves data from Jedis. Each instance has it's own instance of my Jedis server map and it's own instance of each JedisPool.

So, I am asynchronously calling different instances of JedisPool which have the same pool configuration. Is it safe to do this? To concurrently query the same endpoint using different individual instances of JedisPool? If so, any suggestions why I'm seeing the below exception?

```
 Unexpected end of stream.. Retrying...redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:198) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:132) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:196) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
```